# Google script onEdit function not triggers if same value entered in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to run onEdit function in a google script. There is a cell, where all entered value summarized. But if the same value entered in a cell, it is not triggering.
e.g: cell value : 300. When 100 entered, new cell value will be 400. It works. But, if cell value: 300, when 300 entered again (to let it be 300+300=600), onEdit not triggers.
(a time ago i had a workaround: i wrote a postfix after the number from my script, and a user only write a number into a cell. But with that workaround, buit in functions which works with numbers not worked.)

Do you have any tips how to trigger onEdit in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    Browser.msgBox("onEdit fired!");
}
```

[image]

A3 cell now contains value= 200. If i write in cell A3 200 again, message box not show up -> onEdit function not fired. If i write any other value than 200, it works.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is really difficult for someone to answer a codeless question because they have to make many assumptions which cost time for both you and the answerer (volunteer). Besides the code part, provide details on how you execute your code and if you get any errors in the execution page. In other words, provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite):

> The `onEdit(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user **changes the
> value** of any cell in a spreadsheet.

In your case, no value is changed since you are replacing `200` with `200` therefore `onEdit` is not executed/triggered. This is an intended behaviour and not a bug or anything like that.

A different approach would be to delete the value in the cell and type again `200` or use [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) but this should be used carefully since a code is going to be executed every time you change your selection.